# Github Pages not deploying remote theme

Tags: git, github, jekyll, web-deployment, github-pages

I am trying to use remote theme on Github Pages for the first time. Although the theme works fine on the local server, it is not being deployed on the Github Pages server. I can open the page but the theme is not being loaded correctly.

I already tried the modifications to `_config.yml` mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll), [here](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme).

Here's the link to my [repo](https://github.com/kgarg8/Text-Style-Transfer). Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your setup. Jekyll uses `theme` in the config, not `remote_theme` unless you are using Ben Balter's plugin. The thing is, I'm not sure what Balter's plugin does that vanilla Jekyll doesn't do. You might need to ask specifics in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/issues). The other issue is, you said you are trying to use a theme but you're referencing this repo in the config file. What theme do you want to use? One other thought: you might be having problems since the source is in `gh-pages`. Try moving it to `master`.

Comment: (1) From Github Docs(first link in my question): "To use any other Jekyll theme hosted on GitHub, type remote_theme: THEME-NAME, replacing THEME-NAME with the name of the theme as shown in the README of the theme's repository."

(2) I want to use texture theme, but when I use texture in the config.yml, it doesn't work. I even tried ```thelehhman/texture``` but it is still the same situation.

(3) Moving to ```master``` is definitely not the solution. Previously I was using Github default theme and it was not the ```master``` branch, still it was working fine.

Comment: Are you getting emails from GitHub with build errors? This is going to be very difficult for someone to troubleshoot without being able to see your build environment. If it's working locally but not on GitHub you may need to contact their support to ask for help.

Comment: No build errors received. Support on Github community?

Comment: You could try the community, but I meant contacting GitHub staff: https://support.github.com/request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the `remote_theme` name primarily, it was incorrectly mentioned on the theme page.

Updated `remote_theme: samarsault/texture` from `thelehhman/texture` and `baseurl:''` to `baseurl:`